# Show that $\{(r_n-\frac{1}{m},r_n+\frac{1}{m})\mid r_n\in \mathbb Q \wedge m\in \mathbb N\}$ is a basis for standard topology of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

In [my book](https://books.google.com/books?id=EdCkDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22the%20standard%20topology%20consists%20of%20the%20sets%22&source=bl&ots=cbe_-j05qJ&sig=ACfU3U3dg1LP3lgMVImedL6LZEArEaQI3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0hM2b5YfoAhWBuJ4KHbWrCgIQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20standard%20topology%20consists%20of%20the%20sets%22&f=false), $B=\{(r_n-\frac{1}{m},r_n+\frac{1}{m})\mid r_n\in \mathbb Q \wedge m\in \mathbb N\}$ is cited as a basis for standard topology of $\mathbb R$. First, how is this proved and second, what's the motivation behind writing the basis in this way? Why not just write the basis as $\{(r,s)\mid r,s\in \mathbb Q\}$?

I know that to show it's a basis, we need to show:
(i): $x \in \mathbb R$ belongs to some $b \in B$.

(ii): Let $b_1,b_2\in B$, then for $x \in b_1 \cap b_2$, there exists $b_3 \in B$ such that $x \in b_3 \subset b_1 \cap b_2$.

For (i): $\forall x \exists (r\in \mathbb Q) \ni x\in (r-1,r+1)$ and since $(r-1,r+1)\in B$ we're done. (is this proof good?)

I don't know what to do for (ii). Also I don't know how to show this is the standard topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I think the form of the base chosen as $(r_n-\frac{1}{m}, r_n + \frac{1}{m})$ is indeed a bit weird. $(q,r): q, r \in \Bbb Q$ is more natural if we look at $\Bbb R$ as a linearly ordered space, the first form is a more metric form and sees it as a set of open balls $B(r_n, \frac{1}{m})$, in accordance with the general way we can construct a countable base in a metric space that has a countable dense subset, as in [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3572226/4280).

Both are valid bases (and the first is a subset of the second of course).

In fact: in a second countable space every base for the topology has a countable subset that is also a base for the space. So we can have many countable bases, all different.

As to the second part: you're confused: you **don't** have to show that the family obeys the 2 axioms for it to be the base for *some* topology : you need to show it is a base **for the standard topology** which means exactly two things:

1. Every $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is open in the standard topology.
2. For every open set $O$ in the standard topology and every $x \in O$ we have a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq O$

(2. is equivalent to saying "every open set $O$ in the standard topology is a union of members from $\mathcal{B}$)")

And these facts are quite evident; for a metric view of 2., look at the linked question I mentioned where this is done in general for all metric spaces and countable dense subsets, and for $\Bbb R$ as an ordered space we can use the rational intervals: a basic open set is $(a,b)$ and we can find for any $x \in (a,b)$, we can find rationals $q,r$ such that $a < q < x < r < b$ and then $x \in (q,r) \subseteq (a,b)$. Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3572281/4280) about $\Bbb Q$ being dense.

1. is evident in both views: open balls $(B(r_n, \frac{1}{m})$ are open and open intervals $(q,r)$ are standard open, respectively.

And that's why it is a base *for the standard topology*.

Comment: So is this correct: if a basis satisfies 1. and 2. you mention, they definitely satisfy (i) and (ii) that I mentioned and so it's enough to show 1. and 2.?

Comment: @Ali yes, my 1 and 2 are necessary and sufficient for showing it to be a base for the usual topology. Your i plus ii for showing it is a base for *some* topology.

Comment: Thanks. Also, can we show 2. without reference to the metric? Something like: let $O\in \tau$ (standard topology) and $x\in O$ then $\exists r\in \mathbb Q ,n\in \mathbb N \ni x\in (r-\frac{1}{n},r+\frac{1}{n})\subseteq O$ so $\exists B \in \mathcal B \ni x\in B\subseteq O$. Although I'm a bit fuzzy on why every point of any open interval from $\tau$ should belong to an interval of the form $(r-\frac{1}{n},r+\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: @Ali You need yo show **why** such a $r$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ exist. Not just claim it. Adapt the metric proof I linked too: open metric balls are just open intervals in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof of the fact that each $x\in\mathbb R$ belongs to some element of $B$ is correct.

If $r,r^\star\in\mathbb Q$ and $m,m^\star\in\mathbb N$, consider the set$$\left(r-\frac1m,r+\frac1m\right)\cap\left(r^\star-\frac1{m^\star},r^\star+\frac1{m^\star}\right).\tag1$$If it is not empty and if $x$ belongs to it, then, since $(1)$ is an element of the standard topology $\mathcal T$ of $\mathbb R$, there are $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ such that $(1)\supset(a,b)$. Now take $q\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb Q$. There is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $a<q-\frac1n$ and that $q+\frac1n<b$. So$$\left(q-\frac1n,q+\frac1n\right)\subset\left(r-\frac1m,r+\frac1m\right)\cap\left(r^\star-\frac1{m^\star},r^\star+\frac1{m^\star}\right).$$

So, yes, $B$ is the base of some topology $\mathcal T_B$. Since each element of $B$ is an element of $\mathcal T$ and since each element $\mathcal T$ is the union of elements of $B$, $\mathcal T_B=\mathcal T$.