# Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Then the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

[image]

Question: Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Then the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ are dense
in $\mathbb{R}$.

This is how I proved this. However, I was wondering whether I can avoid using epsilon ($\epsilon$) and use something else as its just an arbitrary point. Kindly check and let me know whether my proof is correct or wrong. If needs a good notation and some changes to be the "best proof", don't hesitate to let me know and i will be more than happy to do that.

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just skip the introduction and state that the standard base of $\Bbb R$ is $$\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b): a < b, a, b \in \Bbb R\}$$

A set $D \subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ iff every non-empty open set intersects $D$. And given a base $\mathcal{B}$ for $X$ this is equivalent to every $\emptyset \neq B \in \mathcal{B}$ intersects $D$, as base sets are open and all open sets are unions of basic sets. (No need for this $\epsilon$ stuff you're doing, also considering limit points is unneccesary.)

Now you need some basic fact about $\Bbb R$ from your "history": what is the definition of $\Bbb R$ you're using? If we stay in "order mode", one way to define the reals is as the order completetion of $\Bbb Q$ (adding supremums to subsets of $\Bbb Q$ that are bounded above but have no $\sup$ yet, essentially).

You need to know the following fact about $\Bbb Q$ vis à vis $\Bbb R$:

$$\forall x,y \in \Bbb R: (x < y) \to (\exists q \in \Bbb Q: (x < q \land q < r))\tag{1}$$

And from this it follows right away that every $(a,b) \in \mathcal B$ intersects $\Bbb Q$, it's a basic fact about $\Bbb R$. It follows from how $\Bbb R$ is constructed from $\Bbb Q$. If $(1)$ is part of the fact you can use (and I surely hope it is), then the proof is immediate after noting what the standard base for $\Bbb R$ is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting this alternate method....this sounds great. Will surely use it.